# VBA Shape.Fill.UserPicture doesn't load the picture

Tags: vba, excel

I am using the Fill.UserPicture property to change the image displayed in a shape but the image doesn't get redrawn/refreshed. If I manually right-click the shape and do Change Picture and then paste in the same path and file name (copied from the VBA) it works.

[this SO page says that it worked for them](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10169011/using-vba-to-change-picture)

Any reason why this might be?

I have tried making the Fill not visible first. I'm using Excel 2016.

EDIT: Added the code

```
Dim shpImage As Shape
Dim sNewImagePathAndName As String

sNewImagePathAndName = GetImageFromWebsite(sLineNumber)

Set shpImage = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Images").Shapes("shpTemplateImage")

With shpImage
    If sNewImagePathAndName <> vbNullString Then
        .Fill.Visible = msoFalse
        .Fill.UserPicture PictureFile:=sNewImagePathAndName
        Debug.Print sNewImagePathAndName
        .Fill.Visible = msoTrue
    End If
End With
```

Example of sNewImagePathAndName: "H:\My Documents\Project One\Development\Visual Stock Pack\TS03N50NBLK_Large_F_1.jpg"

Comment: Can you show the code that does not work for you?

Comment: Please re-read [mcve].

Comment: It turns out I had inserted a Picture and not a Shape with a Picture inside it. So the code now works.

Comment: Should this get closed or kept if I make this the answer?