# How to select multiple pictures on Excel and changing them with VBA

Tags: excel, vba, image

The problem is : I am using Tanex TW2021 label on my work and it has 21 cells, and each cell has one photo (customer's private label)

As each product has its own label, I have to change those pictures one by one (because Excel does not allow to change multiple selection of pictures)

So I want a button which makes this selection of 21 pictures and change all of them with one click.

Below you can see a sample picture of how it looks like...

[The Label](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bcJ5w.jpg)

I have tried this small code, it selects the pictures (as you will see there "Resim" but does not change them.

```
Range("A2").Select
ActiveSheet.Shapes.Range(Array("24 Resim")).Select
ActiveSheet.Shapes.Range(Array("24 Resim", "25 Resim")).Select 
ActiveSheet.Shapes.Range(Array("24 Resim", "25 Resim", "26 Resim")).Select 
ActiveSheet.Shapes.Range(Array("24 Resim", "25 Resim", "26 Resim", _ "27 Resim")).Select 
ActiveSheet.Shapes.Range(Array("24 Resim")).Change
```

Comment: We can help you write your own code but we don't want to write code for you. Therefore, post the code you wrote even if it doesn't work and ask how to get it to work.

Comment: I have tried this small code, it selects the pictures (as you will see there "Resim" but does not change them.

Range("A2").Select
    ActiveSheet.Shapes.Range(Array("24 Resim")).Select
    ActiveSheet.Shapes.Range(Array("24 Resim", "25 Resim")).Select
    ActiveSheet.Shapes.Range(Array("24 Resim", "25 Resim", "26 Resim")).Select
    ActiveSheet.Shapes.Range(Array("24 Resim", "25 Resim", "26 Resim", _
        "27 Resim")).Select
    ActiveSheet.Shapes.Range(Array("24 Resim")).Change

Comment: Please modify your question. Nobody will sort your code presented in a comment, especially since your question is obviously lacking this information. Eventually, you will get an answer to your question, not to your comment.

Comment: As i am new on this platform, trying to understand how it works, so please forgive me about the mistakes or disorders...

Comment: What exactly will you be changing? You will probably want to loop through the 21 `Pictures` and apply the changes to each of them. If you mean to move, copy or delete them, then it would make sense to write their names to an array and using the array as the parameter to do the operation in one go. Please do clarify.

Comment: See a previous question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10169011/using-vba-to-change-picture)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you have a single sheet with all 21 images on then delete in turn the existing ones and create new ones the same size in the same place with the new image. See answers [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10169011)

```vb
Option Explicit

Dim FSO As Object, fd As Object, ar() As String
    Dim ws As Worksheet, img As Shape, img2 As Shape, sImageFile As String
    Dim n As Integer, w As Single, h As Single, x As Single, y As Single

    ' select image file
    Set FSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    Set fd = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFilePicker)
    With fd
        .InitialFileName = ThisWorkbook.Path
        .InitialView = msoFileDialogViewList
        .AllowMultiSelect = False
    End With

    If fd.Show <> -1 Then
        Exit Sub
    End If
    sImageFile = fd.SelectedItems(1)

    'Update Sheet1
    ReDim ar(100)
    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1)
    For Each img In Sheet1.Shapes
        ' exclude buttons
        If InStr(1, img.Name, "button", vbTextCompare) = 0 Then
            ' existing label
            x = img.Left
            y = img.Top
            w = img.Width
            h = img.Height
            ' delete existing
            img.Delete
            ' create new in same place
            Set img2 = ws.Shapes.AddPicture(sImageFile, msoFalse, msoTrue, x, y, w, h)
            ar(n) = img2.Name
            n = n + 1
        End If
    Next
    ReDim Preserve ar(n - 1)
    Sheet1.Shapes.Range(ar).Select ' select all
    MsgBox n & " images changed", vbInformation, sImageFile
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, this code worked almost well, except one thing : it adds the selected picture to command button as well. How we can solve this?

Comment: the button located on the sheet to start action, not above the labels by the way...

Comment: @syrsin Put the the delete/create lines inside an IF block with a condition like `IF y<x THEN` . Determine x by adding `debug.print w,y` before the delete. It should be obvious what the y value for the button is. Assuming the button is the lowest image on the sheet.

Comment: I have added these lines :

If y < x Then
        ' delete existing
        img.Delete
        Debug.Print w, y
        ' create new in same place
        ws.Shapes.AddPicture sImageFile, msoFalse, msoTrue, x, y, w, h
        n = n + 1
        End If

but this time it changed 6 images included the button...

Comment: The code starts like below :

'Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
    
    Dim FSO As Object, fd As Object
    Dim ws As Worksheet, img As Shape, sImageFile As String
    Dim n As Integer, w As Single, h As Single, x As Single, y As Single'

Comment: Finally! Thank you very much my friend! Now it does not change the button to a picture.

Now i have another question "can we make all the pictures selected at the end to resize?"

Comment: You are perfect! Works very well, many thanks for your efforts and patience! I need to have class for VBA from you if there is one in online? :)

Answer (score 0):

I have tried this small code, it selects the pictures (as you will see there "Resim" but does not change them.

'''Range("A2").Select ActiveSheet.Shapes.Range(Array("24 Resim")).Select ActiveSheet.Shapes.Range(Array("24 Resim", "25 Resim")).Select ActiveSheet.Shapes.Range(Array("24 Resim", "25 Resim", "26 Resim")).Select ActiveSheet.Shapes.Range(Array("24 Resim", "25 Resim", "26 Resim", _ "27 Resim")).Select ActiveSheet.Shapes.Range(Array("24 Resim")).Change'''

Answer (score 0):

In VBA, a picture is an "object". In Windows, a picture is in a file. You can use Windows Explorer to browse for a picture file. In [this thread](http://%20https://www.exceltip.com/general-topics-in-vba/insert-pictures-using-vba-in-microsoft-excel.html) you can learn how to assign a picture file to a VBA object.

View the vba object as a container. You can put one picture into it or another (but not two), just by changing the file name that you assign to it. In the code

```
Set p = ActiveSheet.Pictures.Insert(PictureFileName)
```

the object is called `p` and the *PictureFileName* is a variable holding a file name. By changing the file name `p` will hold a different picture.

Your Tanex software creates one label, probably as something like an outside wrapper containing both the picture object and text. It then multiplies that wrapper 21 times. That process is not part of Excel. From your code it appears like the "wrapper" is an Excel "Shape" or perhaps a collection of 21 shapes. Since you can select the shape you can also access its components. You just have to try out how to do it. Perhaps the picture itself is the "Shape" (a shape is also a VBA object). It might also be an `InlineShape` which is a particular type of `Shape`.

This code (courtesy of MrExcel.Com) shows you how to assign a picture file to an existing shape.

```
With ActiveSheet.Shapes("Oval 7").Fill
    .UserPicture "C:\Users\RickXL\Pictures\HW Diagrams\Gigaport.png"
End With
```

Replace the shape name "Oval 7" with a name like "Resim 24" in your project. The following code might give you the name of the file of the existing picture which you want to replace.

```
Msgbox Activesheet.Shapes("Resim 24").Fill.UserPicture
```

Your label program probably groups the labels into an array. I don't know. You will just have to apply what you know and what I tell you here plus what you can research on the web and find the solution through trial and error. Good luck.